# Handling long timestep sequences in LSTM

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, lstm

I'm trying to use LSTM to predict information on timestep sequences.

My data looks that way: I have few different samples of relatively long sequences (>100000 timesteps) and I'm trying to solve a N-class classification problem where each sample is labeled as different ID. Now I'm trying to understand how to properly prepare my data so the LSTM will train on each sample individually.

In the most basic case, I just feed each sample completely to the network:

```
model = models.Sequential()
model.add(layers.Embedding(FEATURES_NUMBER, 30))
model.add(layers.LSTM(32, return_sequences=True))

model.compile(optimizer="adam",
              loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['acc'])

history = model.fit(train_data,
                      train_labels,
                      epochs=10,
                      batch_size=128,
                      validation_data=(validation_data,validation_labels)
                     )
```

Where train_data is of shape: (4, 100000, 1).

But I'm being told by many blog posts around (like [here](https://machinelearningmastery.com/truncated-backpropagation-through-time-in-keras/)) that training LSTM on very long sequences might harm the training. So, I don't understand how to properly split the data in correspondence with the LSTM internal state.

I  can split each 100000 long sequence to 500 long sub-sequences and then my data will be of shape: (800, 500, 1). But can I tell the LSTM to still make sense of the larger sequences (Keep internal state between sub-sequences of the same larger sequence and re-initialize it when switching to new sequence)?

I'd be happy if someone could shed some light over that process!

Comment: Maybe you can use one-dimensional iterated dilated CNN to extract features on long sequences, and then use LSTM on shorter sequence features.

Answer (score 0):

The problem has been here for a while. Not sure if you are still interested in my humble two cents. Here is the thing about LSTM, as elegantly designed as it is, it still suffers from vanishing gradients and/or exploding gradients. Adding a forget gate for the cell state alleviates the problem as when a forget gate outputs 0, the back propagation process stops "flowing" backwards at that gate. However, this does not mean LSTM is free from exploding/vanishing gradients when you feed an infinitely long sequence into it. Just image a case where the forget gate output 1 50 times in a row and the gradients for the last output using BPTT would look very similar to the original RNN as the gates are "turned off".

Why would that happen? Because your initial set of params are likely not optimal. And also because a long sequence would requires BPTT through more time steps and thus make chances of that happening higher. You can try training you LSTM on your segmented data subsets.